# Why is the speed of drag slowed down with increase in the width of the container using Jquery draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using Jquery draggable and there are many images loaded in the container but when i drag towards left new CSS properties(left/right)are computed by draggable(jquery)> But when my width(more images in the container) is more. It takes long time to drag.

Tried   making the transition 0 for all. But it didnt help much.

```
<div id="image-list" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 3224px; left: -1086px; right: auto; top: 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without a working example, but the bigger the element, or the more content it has, the more there is for your CPU to process for every single pixel you drag. Hence on an underpowered machine it can tend to stutter.

Comment: nothing related to your code , it's  cpu  probelm !

Comment: @SpringerF, when written in CPP , drag is smooth but makes lot of difference in Javascript(Jquery:Draggable). How can it be related to Hardware then ?

Comment: make a snippet here to test it